# Cygwin no available download site

Tags: cygwin

I have tried from my office it show available download site. Then I used same installer (setup-x86_64.exe) at home it not show anything. Both my pc (office and home) i set up google dns. Is it because im using wireless connection at home? Please advise. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Has to be a networking issue. Proxy, DNS, etc. The download sites are pulled from the web, similar to the package list. If you aren't receiving them, then the program "can't get there from here".

Comment: Could be a firewall issue. One screen before that, you get the option to chose "Direct connection", "Internet Explorer Proxy Settings", and "Use HTTP / FTP Proxy". Whatever it was you chose, try the others. ;-)

Comment: Hi @DevSolar. Already did and the result still same :)

Comment: Bugger. I remember I had this problem at one time, but absolutely cannot remember what the issue at hand was... [have you tried turning it off and on again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2Ph8zwpNyI) (a.k.a., remove setup.exe and directory, reboot, and start over)? I use Cygwin successfully on multiple boxes even behind corporate firewalling, and it *does* work... is the setup.exe recent? "Install from internet" selected? "All users" selected (if possible, i.e. local admin rights)? Personally I am using "Internet Explorer Proxy Settings" in the connection tab.

Comment: As *itachi* already correctly answered, **enabling TLS 1.2** did the trick! But just beware if you use another user for running the setup (e.g. local admin with elevated rights): Remember to change the options for **that** user ;-) (Silly, but I stumbled on this another 5 minutes...) Btw. sorry for opening another answer but due to missing reputation neither upvoting nor commenting *itachi*s answer is possible for me (for now) :-/ Cheers

Comment: "setup-x86_64.exe --no-admin"  This worked for me

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56068181/1441272) from itachi was for me the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 39):

I changed my setting in "Select Your Internet Connection" to "Use System Proxy Settings" instead of "Direct Connection". It worked like a charm.

Comment: I had to restart the Installer and then select "Use Internet Explorer Proxy" (couldn't just do it after seeing a blank list) and this finally worked (after trying many other things).

Comment: This is now called "Use System Proxy Settings". Be sure to restart the application and select that radio button before hitting next.

Answer (score 21):

Just go to website
https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html

Chose the mirror web address nearest to you by clicking right and select the option "SAVE LINK ADDRESS" from the menu.

Paste it into the "USER URL" then click "ADD" and press "NEXT". Hope it will work. Good Luck.......!

Comment: Cygwin gives me the error message "Unable to get setup from < urlhere >" when I try to add one of those manually.

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: @AaronFranke Try using an http/https site, not an ftp one.

Comment: @Leponzo For me HTTPS did not work, while FTP did.

Answer (score 17):

I just met the same problems. At the very beginning, I chose the first option which is directly connect, but I can not get any downloading websites as the image showed above. Then I tried to back and chose the second one which is select your internet collection, the same result is displayed on the screen.

The solution is that we have to restart the installer and directly choose the second option. If you still don't get any websites, please be patient, try one more but still need to restart the installer. I just tried three times, maybe four times, which I can not remember, but it worked finally.

Hoped that can help you guys.

Comment: I was behind proxy setting settings so I closed and restarted the installer and second time selected the Proxy setting options, it did work

Answer (score 16):

Had the same error today, my solution was to :

**move the setup-x86_64.exe out of the Download folder into e.g. c:\tmp**

i think the cygwin setup process has some problems with creating a temporary file in the same directory of its installer due to a lack of permissions and does not show an error message

Comment: how stupid that this answer worked for me, my homedrive cannot download these files. I moved the installer to C and had to add a mirror and now the installer runs! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 14):

The solution for me was enabling TLS 1.2 support in Internet Properties. But hold on! You'd better update your Windows before, because there is an update that [enables support for this protocol by default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi). If you don't want to update your Windows, for reasons, follow these steps:

1. Go to Internet Properties, you can find this in start menu, in control panel, or hit **Win + R** and run: `Inetcpl.cpl`.
2. Go to "Advanced" tab.
3. Scroll to "Security" section.
4. Check **Use TLS 1.2** option.

Run Cygwin installer again and now it should work. If not, maybe try with other security options.

### How did I find out this

After a few failed install attempts, I decided to look for some hints in Event Viewer, and to my surprise, I found them. In *System* logs I spot lots of errors from *Schannel* service with a meaningless description:

> The following fatal alert was received: 70.

I Googled for further explanations. Errors like these are caused by SSL failures, so something wrong was happening between Cygwin installer and Cygwin site. Something in my head told me to check Internet Properties for options relating to security, so I did and I found disabled protocols.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Enabling TLS 1.2 in Internet Options worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I do not have admin privileges on this windows 10 host, but this worked:

```
setup-x86_64.exe -B -O -s http://mirror.clarkson.edu/cygwin
```

which allowed me to install cygwin from that one mirror site.

Comment: Too may corrupt packages.

Answer (score 6):

- Step1: select use internet setting.
- Step2: "http://cygwin.refractal.net/" add this URL.

This works for me.

Also, https://cygwin.com/mirrors.lst has several alternate URL's, depending upon the request location (your location).

Answer (score 5):

Do you have K9 filter installed by any chance ? I have the same problem [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967229/cygwin-download-site-empty-with-k9-filter-installed), but I **do** know my issue is the K9 filter.

Answer (score 5):

Add  one of the site in  http://cygwin.com/mirrors.lst manually 
and select one of the internet connection type which is appropriate for your internet connection. and proceed...it worked for me

Answer (score 5):

i found a solution to this problem:

first, go to https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html , look for your location and click onto the FTP link.

Then, you should see 4 folders:

noarch,
unsupported,
x86,
x86_64

click on "go back" or something like this (go back 1 folder). 
Then you should see a many folders. Search the"cygwin" folder and simply drag it to your desktop. Now you should have a shortcut to this FTP Folder. Now, right-click the shortcut and click onto "properties" and copy the URL.

Now, you can open the installation program.
Click on "Install from Internet",
All Users / Just Me (your choice),
Use System Proxy Settings.
Now you will get an error message (if you already got that error, it wont show up again). Ignore the error and it will ask you for "available Download Sites". 
Paste the URL from the shortcut into the "User URL" and click on "add".
Then, a "Select Package" Window will show up. click on "all" and then on "next".

Finished!

(Im using firefox and windows 7 32bit VM VB)

Now some guys will ask: Why didnt you just put the ftp link directly into the setup?

Well, i tried that and setup crashed on me every single time. With the shortcut it worked fine.

I hope this will help. (my english skills are trash, i know)

Comment: This worked for me but I went about it a little different as I couldn't drag the "cygwin" folder as described to my desktop. Instead I just right clicked on the link and then properties. It showed me a mirror link like ftp://mirrors.syringanetworks.net/cygwin and in the installer when it asked for url of mirror links I added this link and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

"Run as administrator" did the trick for me ....
(Win 7) If run without the list is blank, for whatever reason admin privileges are needed for the mirror list to load.

Comment: i also had to manually enter a mirror site. I used http://mirror.clarkson.edu/cygwin

Answer (score 2):

- In Select Connection Type Page, Select Direct Connection and click Next
- User URL text box ftp://cygwin.mirrors.pair.com and Click Add
- Select the same URL from **Available Download Sites** list and proceed Next.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Disabling kaspersky solved it. There are a list of programs known to interfere with cygwin functionality. Please find the list here [here](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda)(4.44)

Answer (score 1):

Solution
Put one of mirrors to the URL window of installer.
If list of mirror urls is not available, use the below link to get list of 
[mirror urls](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OR0Rkf9v4GEJ:https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html+&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ua)

Also here is working [mirror url](http://mirror-hk.koddos.net/cygwin/)

Answer (score 0):

A silly problem-solution with the same symptoms, sharing for future reference - I was using an old installer, downloading the latest version fixed this immediately

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time trying different things, I was able to get it working after pasting the ftp link in the cygwin User url input box. Go to the [Cygwin mirrors page](https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html) and then search for ftp and copy any of the ftp link by right clicking on it. Now restart the setup wizard from starting and then copy this ftp link and you should be able to download the dependencies. The below screenshot highlights the ftp that I used.

[image: Screenshot of the Cygwin mirrors page]

Answer (score -3):

You Should try adding this site
it is working for me.

Japan: [ftp.iij.ad.jp](ftp://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/cygwin/)(ftp), [ftp.jaist.ac.jp](ftp://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/cygwin/)(ftp), [ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp](ftp://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/cygwin/)(ftp), [ftp.iij.ad.jp](http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/cygwin/)(http), [ftp.jaist.ac.jp](http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/cygwin/)(http), [ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp](http://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/cygwin/)(http)