# Cygwin Download Site empty with K9 filter installed

Tags: filter, cygwin

I have the same problem as listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673949/cygwin-no-available-download-site), briefly, when I try to install Cygwin I have empty list of sites. (BTW the [Cygwin mirrors site](http://cygwin.com/mirrors.html) works fine from my browser!)

The problem I know is due to the K9 filter I have installed.

I tired whatever K9 advises to disable the filter per [this link](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/support/kb/K9155.html) but I can only install Cygwin when K9 is completely uninstalled.

Any suggestions how to have K9 and install Cygwin ?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.  I don't know why this is happening, but I've noticed that cygwin setup can only fetch ftp links and not http links for setup.ini.  Perhaps it is possible to prefetch or obtain the mirror list via ftp? Unfortunately I don't see anything under setup --help to do this, or I would add it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple workaround, un-install K9 :)

I **can do** subsequent Cygwin re-installs, *after* Cygwin is installed and K9 Re-installed (there are some setup.ini errors that pop up, which I ignore as Cygwin installer still does what's expected)

So now, it's just a mystery, why **only** the **initial** Cygwin install is the "Download site list" empty?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got it rectified by disabling kaspersky. The issue is due to some applications interfering with cygwin. The list of applications that are known to interfere can be found [here](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-10/msg00394.html)(section 4.44)